# Execute sql query from sql file

Tags: php

I want to include all tables from a database "shop" to mydatabase `newshop`. I export that "shop" database, and now it is named as `shop.sql`. Is there any way to execute whole query from that file instead of importing directly to database `newshop`.

Comment: (don't re-post questions; I've merged the duplicate)

Comment: Judging from a deleted question, he seems to be asking that is there anyway to run a .sql file from *php* .

Answer (score 9):

I think what you need might be:

`$ mysql -u $USERNAME -p < "$SQLFILENAME"`

Where $USERNAME is the user name of mysql like `root` and $SQLFILENAME is the name of the sql file ('`shop.sql`' in this case).

The above command will ask you to type in password. If you don't want to do that every time, you can use '--password=$PASSWORD' BUT be careful. This password may be saved in history and it might be in the wrong hand (If you run it from PHP, it may not be a problem).

OR you can use mysqli to run it.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = file_get_contents("shop.sql");

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query))
     echo "Success";
else 
     echo "Fail";
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this question is tagged with PHP, here's how you could do it:

```
mysql_query('USE newshop');
$queries = file('shop.sql');
while(list($i, $query) = each($queries)){
    $query = trim($query, ';');
    if(!empty($query) && $query != 'USE shop'){
        @mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Make sure "`USE shop`" in the `if` statement matches whatever syntax is used in the SQL file. For instance, you might need to make it `USE 'shop'` or `USE schemaname.shop`. Or, if there's no `USE` command in there at all, you can just take that condition right out.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mysql -u username -p
>>> show databases;
>>> use foo;
>>> source /home/mannu/file.sql
```

I believe that's what you're looking for? Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you [might be interested in](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/05/run-sql-file-from-php.html):

```
<?php

  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'password';
  $db = 'newshop';
  $file =dirname(__FILE__).'\\'.'shop.sql';
  $mySQLDir='"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe"';



    if ($dbpass != '') {
        $cmd = $mySQLDir.' -h '.$dbhost.' --user='.$dbuser.' --password='.$dbpass.' < "'.$file.'"';

    } else {
        $cmd = $mySQLDir.' -h '.$dbhost.' --user='.$dbuser.' < "'.$file.'"';
    }

     echo $cmd;  

   exec('"'.$cmd.'"',$out ,$retval);
   echo "\n";
    echo ($retval);

?>
```